# Flaskr url_for with parameters not working when called from javascript to python

Tags: python, flask

I am in the middle of creation of a web application.

In javascript, I make a ajax call to my python script, process and send the result back as response.
/process/ is the route to the python script for the processing of values which are sent as json, namely value1 and value2. I send back response as json setting value in key 'result'.

In the success block of ajax, the value is stored in name_value and this should be passed as parameter to the python routing method.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/process/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "value1" : value1,
                "value2" : value2
               },
        success: function(data) {
            var name = data.result;
            console.log(name);
            window.location.href = "{{url_for('/process2', name=name)}}"
        }
    });
```

Python script:

```
app.route("/process2/<name>")
def process2(name):
    print name
    render_template("user.html", name=name);
```

I am not receiving the parameter value in this case if parameter is passed in url_for. If I hardcode the parameter, I am able to receive the parameter value in the python script as in,

```
window.location.href = "{{url_for('/process2', name='helloworld')}}"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that JS being rendered in the template or is it in a static file? The only way that `url_for` will be turned into the actual URL string by Jinja is if it's part of your template.

Comment: Yes.. its rendered in the template only. Template folder contain my html file within which I have my javascript.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, I have learned that Jinja cannot utilize Javascript variables, like the following:

`window.location.href = "{{ url_for('/process2', name=name) }}"`

If I am wrong about that, somebody please correct me and you shall become my best friend in the SO community.

EDIT:

As Jason Heine mentioned, you can achieve what you want by passing in the `url_for` method as the result in the json:

Python:

```
from flask import jsonify, url_for

@app.route("/process", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():    
    name = 'bubba'  # code to get the name
    return jsonify({
        'result': url_for('process2', name=name),
        'name': name
     })

@app.route("/process2/<string:name>")
def process2(name):
    print name
    render_template("user.html", name=name);
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/process",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { "value1" : value1,
            "value2" : value2
           },
    success: function(data) {
        var route = data.result;
        var name = data.name;
        console.log(route, name);

        window.location.href = route;
    }
});
```

You may also check out the [AJAX with jQuery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/) documention if you have any more questions.

Comment: Or, you could just do the url_for in the route "process" and return it to the ajax call, pull that data, and then pass it to the location.href.

Comment: Ah! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks for the information